# SharePoint Dataview and Attachments

Tags: data-view-web-part

I'm in a DataView (in SharePoint Designer). I'm trying to display a link to an attachment of an item from a custom list. I use this code:

```
               <xsl:element name="sharepoint:AttachmentsField">
                    <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AttachmentsField' does not have
>   a public property named 'xmlns:sharepoint'.

Here's all the XML for the dataview I'm using :

```
 <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="0" Title="Press Release" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{D427625B-B0D6-421A-89C9-697E8428592F}" id="g_d427625b_b0d6_421a_89c9_697e8428592f">
              <DataSources>
                <SharePointWebControls:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Counter&quot;&gt;{PR}&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart2">
                  <SelectParameters>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}"/>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="WebURL" ParameterKey="WebURL" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{sitecollectionroot}"/>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="PR" ParameterKey="PR" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="1"/>
                  </SelectParameters>
                  <DeleteParameters>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}"/>
                  </DeleteParameters>
                  <UpdateParameters>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}"/>
                  </UpdateParameters>
                  <InsertParameters>
                    <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}"/>
                  </InsertParameters>
                </SharePointWebControls:SPDataSource>
              </DataSources>

          <datafields>@Title,Title;@Body,Body;@Publishing_Date,Publishing Date;@Expires,Expires;@ShortDescription,Short Description;@Press_Release_Year,Year;@Item_x0020_Language,Item Language;@ID,ID;@ContentType,Content Type;@Modified,Modified;@Created,Created;@Author,Created By;@Editor,Modified By;@_UIVersionString,Version;@Attachments,Attachments;@File_x0020_Type,File Type;@FileLeafRef,Name (for use in forms);@FileDirRef,Path;@FSObjType,Item Type;@_HasCopyDestinations,Has Copy Destinations;@_CopySource,Copy Source;@ContentTypeId,Content Type ID;@_ModerationStatus,Approval Status;@_UIVersion,UI Version;@Created_x0020_Date,Created;@FileRef,URL Path;</datafields>
          <XSL>
            <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:sharepoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
              <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
              <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
              <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
              <xsl:param name="ListID">{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}</xsl:param>
              <xsl:param name="WebURL">{sitecollectionroot}</xsl:param>
              <xsl:param name="PR">1</xsl:param>
              <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
              <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
              </xsl:template>
              <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
                <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
                  <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:template>
              <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
                <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                  <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:template>
              <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
                <div class="prItemTitle"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Publishing_Date) , 1036,'yyyy/MM/dd')" /> -  <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></div>
                 <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@Attachments='1' or msxsl:string-compare(string(@Attachments),'Yes','','i')=0 or msxsl:string-compare(string(@Attachments),'True','','i')=0"><xsl:value-of select="@Attachments" /></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                 </xsl:choose>
                <div class="prItemBody"><xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></div>

                <xsl:element name="sharepoint:AttachmentsField">
                    <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>                        

              </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
          </XSL>
          <parameterbindings>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{E1BBFD8D-6052-477B-921D-A3055E69399B}"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="WebURL" Location="None" DefaultValue="{sitecollectionroot}"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="PR" Location="QueryString(PR)" DefaultValue="1"/>
          </parameterbindings>
        </WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

The `xmlns:sharepoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` declaration is there, so I really don't know why I get that error...

**UPDATE #1 :**

If I try to use this code  (from the suggested method) :

`<SharePoint:AttachmentsField ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server" Visible="true"/>`

I get another error:

> Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AttachmentsField' does not have
>   a public property named 'xmlns:sharepoint'.

**Update #2 :**
By the way, the DataView is in a page layout. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post my Marc Anderson and see if it helps: http://sympmarc.com/2010/05/26/using-sharepointattachmentsfield-in-a-dvwps-xsl/

Comment: That's the method I tried. I updated it with another way of displaying it. still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised to hear that the method described by Anderson's blog didn't work.  Anyhow, I was approached with the same problem, but I took a different approach for the fun of it. I used JavaScript + jQuery to modify the list.

1. Navigate to your SharePoint site
   using your web browser.
2. Select the list. (Usually on the
   left hand side depending on your
   theme and permissions).
3. Make sure the “Attachments” columns
   is part of the view. If  it is, skip
   the next step.
4. Modify the current view by clicking
   on “All Items” then “Modify this
   View”. Then be sure the 
   “Attachments”  column is selected.
   Then click OK. Also, make it the
   first column if it is not.
5. Now click on “Site Actions” , “Edit
   Page”, then “Add a Web Part”
6. Add a “Content Editor Web Part”
   Paste the JavaScript described in this blog [post](http://www.mindovercode.com/2010/09/06/download-attachments-from-a-list/).

Mind you this approach has its disadvantages as described in the blog.

Comment: Well, I ended up adding a "hyperlink" field in the content type then I just display it. Less of a good solution for the client but the JAvaScript has it's problems too (it's an Internet WebSite, not an Intranet so...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this answer, stumbled across it from google. But the problem you are having is because the xmlns declaration in your stylesheet has a lowercase S. it should be xmlns:SharePoint